# Dynamically display table in _Layout sidebar

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic, sidebar

I have a sidebar in `_Layout.cshtml` in which I want to dynamically display items from another view/model. I'm not very good at database stuff so I need some help.

Sidebar in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    @if (IsSectionDefined("SideBar")) {
        @RenderSection("SideBar", required: false)
    } else {
        *Here is where I want the table to be displayed*
    }
```

The view I want to display in the sidebar is located in `~/Views/Sidebarpics/index.cshtml`.

If you need more code to be able to help me just ask!

Thanks

**SOLVED**, My solution:

I made a duplicate of SidebarPics/index and named it index2.

_Layout Sidebar:

```
    <div id="sidebar">
        @if (IsSectionDefined("SideBar"))
        {
            @RenderSection("SideBar", required: false)
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Action("Index2", "SidebarPics")
        }
```

HomeController:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

SidebarPicsController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.SidebarPics.ToList());
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        return PartialView(db.SidebarPics.ToList());
    }
```

This might not be the best solution, but it works fine for me and this way it was easy to style them differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either @Html.Partial or @Html.Action depending on whether you need that view to go through a controller or not.

If you just want to load the cshtml without needing to using a controller action then render it as a [partial view](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC):

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Sidebarpics/index.cshtml")
```

If you need to process the view through a controller action then render it as a [child action](http://theshravan.net/blog/child-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc/):

```
@Html.Action("Index", "SidebarPics")
```

EDIT: Add Child Controller Example

EDIT 2: I realized that I had flipped the controller and action parameters.  Action should be first.

EDIT 3: Update to change name of partial index per comments.

Relevent Layout Page Section:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    @if (IsSectionDefined("SideBar")) {
        @RenderSection("SideBar", required: false)
    } else {
        @Html.Action("PartialIndex", "SidebarPics")
    }
</div>
```

Home Controller:

```
 public class HomeController 
 {
      [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult Index() 
      {
           return View();
      }
 }
```

SidebarPics Controller:

```
 public class SidebarPicsController 
 {
      public ActionResult Index() 
      {
           return View(db.SidebarPics.ToList());
      }

      [ChildActionOnly]
      public ActionResult PartialIndex() 
      {
           return PartialView("Index", db.SidebarPics.ToList());
      }
 }
```

I believe it is also possible to omit the ChildActionOnly attribute but then you will have an action that only returns a partial view.

Comment: I've messed around with @Html.Action but I can't get it to work. In which controller should I place the child action? Home or SidebarPics?

Comment: Since you want it to be available in the Layout page and it isn't specifically related to the Home controller I would put it in the SidebarPics controller.  I have updated the post to add an example of the controllers.

Comment: I've added the stuff you recommended and the table now show up in the sidebar! But now I can't visit the original view since the action 'Index' is accessible only by a child request. If I do it like this:




    public class SidebarPicsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.SidebarPics.ToList());
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }




Then the Index()'s collide. Any ideas?
Sorry for not knowing how to make the code show up as code.

Comment: You can change the name of the partial version of the index function.  I have updated the example.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I've solved my problem! It might not be the most efficient way but I don't care.
I did a duplicate of the index and named it index2 and then called that view instead and returned Partialview. This way it was easy to style them aswell. Anyway you helped me alot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call a partial view, using `@Html.Partial` inside of your condition

```
  <div id="sidebar">
        @if (IsSectionDefined("SideBar"))
        {
            @RenderSection("SideBar", required: false)
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Sidebarpics/index.cshtml")
        }
</div>
```

More information about partial views: http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html